# ReactJS Time between dates in real time

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, real-time

I'm trying to figure out how I can make a real-time counter that will increment the seconds without having to refresh my page. Here is my code below. I'm quite new to using ReactJS any hints/help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks..

```
import './Home.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Moment from 'react-moment';

export default class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        var date = new Date();
        const together = "2017-05-14T06:30";


        return (
            <div>
                <p><Moment interval={1000} diff={together} unit="seconds">{date}</Moment> Seconds</p>
                <p><Moment diff={together} unit="minutes">{date}</Moment> Minutes</p>
                <p><Moment diff={together} unit="days">{date}</Moment> Days</p>
                <p><Moment diff={together} unit="months">{date}</Moment> Months</p>
                <p><Moment diff={together} unit="years" decimal>{date}</Moment> Years</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an example of this in the official React docs https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#updating-the-rendered-element

But the gist of it is you need to use `setInterval` to update the state of the component.  That will cause the component to re-render without a page refresh.

In your case, you would want to save `date` to the state's component (e.g. in the constructor) and then read it from the state in render.  Then use `setInterval` to update the state every second.

```
import './Home.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Moment from 'react-moment';

export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor() {
         this.state.date = new Date();
    }
    updateTime(){
        var date = this.state.date
        this.setState({date: date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + 1);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        setInterval(this.updateTime, 1000);
    }
    render() {
        const together = "2017-05-14T06:30";


        return (
            <div>
                <p><Moment interval={1000} diff={together} unit="seconds">{this.state.date}</Moment> Seconds</p>
                 // etc.  Everywhere you had date becomes this.state.date
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, Trying today I got a good solution.
If you like it and work please give like. Thank you

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import Moment from "react-moment";
import "moment-timezone";
import moment from "moment";

const Date = () =>{
  const [dateToFormat, setdateToFormat] = useState(moment().toDate().getTime())
  const updateTime = () => {
    let clock = moment().toDate().getTime()
  }
  setInterval(updateTime, 1000)

  useEffect(() => {
    let time = updateTime;
    setdateToFormat(
      time
    );
  },[]);
  
  return(
    <div>
        <Moment interval={1} unit="seconds">
              {dateToFormat}
        </Moment>
    </div>
  )
}


export default Date;
```